# question about postgres json function vs sqlite3 json function syntax where jsonpath is concerned

Tags: java, postgresql, sqlite, jsonpath

I'm working on a project where I've got a java service talking to a database where a json object is stored. The json object is called `scanResultCollection`. It has a top level attribute called `organization`. I've got things set up to where when running in stand alone mode (ie - on my workstation) it uses sqlite. When deployed it will automatically switch to postgres.

here is the relevant piece of code:

```
        EntityManager entityManager = ctx.attribute(App.RESULT_TABLE_ENTITY_MANAGER);
        var criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Result> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Result.class);
        Root<Result> root = criteriaQuery.from(Result.class);

        var organizationPath = JPathHelpers.getJsonPathFor(
                List.of(ScanResultCollection.ORGANIZATION_KEY)
        );
        LOG.info("organizationPath is: {}", organizationPath);
        var predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(
                criteriaBuilder.function(
                        "jsonb_extract_path_text",
                        //"json_extract", // @TODO this should be a config value as it's db specific
                        String.class,
                        // TODO see note in Result entity for why we're not using the generated metamodel for now
                        // TODO when looking into the ScanResultCollection json object
                        root.get(SCAN_RESULT_COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTE),
                        //criteriaBuilder.literal(organizationPath)
                        criteriaBuilder.literal("organization")
                ),
                org
        );

        criteriaQuery.select(root).where(predicate);
        var query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        List<Result> results = query.getResultList();
```

Basically what's happening is the caller is supplying a value for `organization` and we are endeavoring to query the database for all `scanResultCollection` objects with an `organization` value that matches what the caller provided.

For sqlite the function `json_extract` is being employed and the value of `organizationPath` resolves to `$.organization`. All of this works perfectly.

For postgres we need to change the function name to `jsonb_extract_path_text` - no problem as obviously postgres is a different database system than sqlite. The thing that stumped me all day was the fact that `"$.organizationPath"` does NOT work and will always return zero results. In order to get postgres to perform the same work as sqlite it was necessary to supply the string `"organization"` as opposed to the jsonpath form `"$.organization"`.

The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) state the parameter is of type JSONPath and eventually I figured out that to Postgres `JSONPath` means something different than what it means in almost any other use case I know of - especially where the meaning of `$` is concerned.

- [Postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH)
- [Sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) which seems to use the `$` character in the way one might expect for a JSONPath.
- [the draft spec for JSONPath](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base/)
- [Jayway JSONPath dialect](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) (whose author is also helping to write the IETF spec)

**Here are my questions**

- why doesn't `"$.organization"` work in both sqlite and postgres contexts? It looks like in Postgres (and in fact in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-AEBAD813-99AB-418A-93AB-F96BC1658618) and [SqlServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)) the `$` is *"A variable representing the JSON value being queried (the context item)"*. Is not the "context item" the "current item" in which case it would be akin to the root JSON element?
- Is there a way for me to use hibernate (or some other java library) to homogenize the JSONPath syntax so it works across multiple SQL db systems? Given what I'm seeing in the docs my hunch is that the same syntax will work for Postgres, Oracle, and SqlServer, but not Sqlite. It's not a huge deal for this use case as I can easily add another config value that swaps in the context-appropriate JSONPath syntax but if there's a way to do it I'd like to know how for future reference.

In the final analysis it strikes me as odd that major SQL database vendors would implement something as common defacto standardized as JSONPath in a manner incompatible with how the rest of the world uses it - which tells me I'm probably missing something and if so I'm curious as to what that something might be...

ty in advance!

Comment: Well from the `Jayway` link: *Since a JSON structure is usually anonymous and doesn't necessarily have a "root member object" JSONPath assumes the abstract name $ assigned to the outer level object.*. And from the draft spec: *The root node identifier $ refers to the root node of the query  argument, i.e., to the argument as a whole.* Which is how Postgres uses it.

Comment: As to `current item` from `Jayway`: *@  the current object/element *, the draft spec: * The current node identifier @ refers to the current node in the  context of the evaluation of a filter expression*.

Comment: ok but shouldn't "$.organization" work in both cases given yours and my read of the docs?

Comment: I would say yes. Though without some example JSON data, queries and output vs actual output it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: therein lies the question. "$.organization" works for sqlite but returns no results for postgres. For postgres "organization" is the JSONPath string that will produce expected results. What I don't understand is why given what we're both seeing in the documentation

Comment: Again without example data and the queries your using in each case this is not going to go anywhere.

Comment: thanks friend. read the post. everything you need is in there. the query is in the code snippet. the data structure - or at least the piece of it that matters - is described clearly in the post as well.

Comment: I see the path specifier `$.organization`. I don't see the JSON data it is being run against.

Comment: second and third sentence of the post: 

"The json object is called scanResultCollection. It has a top level attribute called organization"

what else do you need to know?

Comment: Good luck and bye.